# Solving a system of equations using the data generated by PowersRepresentations and ParallelTable

Tags: equation-solving, parallelization, number-theory, diophantine-equations, code

*First of all, it is possible to check the code that I am asking for because I know that $x=3051$ must yield at least a solution to the problem.*

Well, I have the following system of equations:

[image]

Now, I need to solve this system for `{n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8,n9}` . The values of $x$ that needs to be tried come from the following code:

```
ParallelTable[
 If[TrueQ[Length[
     Select[Select[PowersRepresentations[n, 3, 2], Times @@ # != 0 &],
       Length[#] == Length[Union[#]] &]] >= 6], n, Nothing], {n, 0, 
  10000}]

(* {314,329,341,...,9998} *)
```

> Question: How can I loop through the values given by the ParallelTable code (`{314,329,341,...,9998}`) in order to check if the system of equations gives a solution for a certain value of $x$?

---

So, the first case to check would be when $x=314$ and the solutions that has to be tried are given by:

```
Select[Select[PowersRepresentations[314, 3, 2], Times @@ # != 0 &], 
Length[#] == Length[Union[#]] &]

(* {{1, 12, 13}, {3, 4, 17}, {3, 7, 16}, {5, 8, 15}, {7, 11, 12}, {8, 9, 
  13}} *)
```

So, we need to try to solve the following system of equations using the possible values, given from the code above (`{{1,12,13},{3,4,17},{3,7,16},{5,8,15},{7,11,12},{8,9,13}}`):

```
x=314;
Solve[{x == n1^2 + n2^2 + n3^2, x == n4^2 + n5^2 + n6^2, 
      x == n7^2 + n8^2 + n9^2, x == n1^2 + n4^2 + n7^2, 
      x == n2^2 + n5^2 + n8^2, x == n3^2 + n6^2 + n9^2}, {n1, n2, n3, n4, 
      n5, n6, n7, n8, n9}]
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are doing, but some thoughts: `xvals = ParallelTable[...]` -- your expression before first question, which gives `{314, 329, ...}`. Now you can use this to substitute for `x` in your system of equations: `ParallelMap[  Solve[{# == n1^2 + n2^2 + n3^2, # == n4^2 + n5^2 + n6^2, # == n7^2 + n8^2 + n9^2, # == n1^2 + n4^2 + n7^2, # == n2^2 + n5^2 + n8^2, # == n3^2 + n6^2 + n9^2}, {n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9}, PositiveIntegers] &, xvals];`, or just for limited range `xvals[[1;;100]]`, then for the next range, because of computation time and memory.

Comment: @Alx You can test the code, but using $x=3051$ you have to find: $$n_1=29,n_2=41,n_3=23,n_4=1,n_5=37,n_6=41,n_7=47,n_8=1,n_9=29$$

Comment: Yes, it gives values from your comment and many other combinations in terms of positive integers.

Comment: @Alx Can you show me what you did. Feel free to post your code as an answer. Thank you very much for thinking with me

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1945487)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post here my comment as an answer (actually I'm not sure this is the right answer). Define table of `x` values (just as given by OP):

```
    xvals = ParallelTable[
   If[TrueQ[
     Length[Select[
        Select[PowersRepresentations[n, 3, 2], Times @@ # != 0 &], 
        Length[#] == Length[Union[#]] &]] >= 6], n, Nothing], {n, 0, 
    10000}];
```

Now we can use this to substitute for `x` when solving the given system of equations, and to speed-up the code we can use `ParallelMap`:

```
ParallelMap[
  Solve[{# == n1^2 + n2^2 + n3^2, # == n4^2 + n5^2 + n6^2, # == 
      n7^2 + n8^2 + n9^2, # == n1^2 + n4^2 + n7^2, # == 
      n2^2 + n5^2 + n8^2, # == n3^2 + n6^2 + n9^2}, {n1, n2, n3, n4, 
     n5, n6, n7, n8, n9}, PositiveIntegers] &, xvals[[;; 50]]];
```

This gives the solution in terms of positive integer numbers, and because of time and memory consumption one can use several ranges of `xvals` (here the first 50 values are used).

One can also solve for particular `x`:

```
x = 3051;
sol=Solve[{x == n1^2 + n2^2 + n3^2, x == n4^2 + n5^2 + n6^2, 
  x == n7^2 + n8^2 + n9^2, x == n1^2 + n4^2 + n7^2, 
  x == n2^2 + n5^2 + n8^2, x == n3^2 + n6^2 + n9^2}, {n1, n2, n3, n4, 
  n5, n6, n7, n8, n9}, PositiveIntegers]
```

This gives many solutions and `{n1 -> 29, n2 -> 41, n3 -> 23, n4 -> 1, n5 -> 37, n6 -> 41, n7 -> 47, n8 -> 1, n9 -> 29}` is among them.

To check if all the solutions are unique we can do:

```
Select[DeleteDuplicates /@ Values[sol], Length[#] == 9 &]
```

In the case of `x = 3051` we have repeated values (1, 29, 41) and this `Select` command gives empty list as an output `{}`, that means there is no unrepeated values.

Using `ParallelTable` (as OP suggested in comments):

```
sol = ParallelTable[
   Solve[{x == n1^2 + n2^2 + n3^2, x == n4^2 + n5^2 + n6^2, 
     x == n7^2 + n8^2 + n9^2, x == n1^2 + n4^2 + n7^2, 
     x == n2^2 + n5^2 + n8^2, x == n3^2 + n6^2 + n9^2, 
     x == n1^2 + n5^2 + n9^2}, {n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9}, 
    PositiveIntegers], {x, 0, 2000}];

Map[Select[Length[#] == 9 &]@*DeleteDuplicates, 
  Values[sol], {2}] //. {} -> Nothing
```

We `Map` at 2nd level (at all sub-lists of `sol`): composition (`@*`) of deleting repeated values (`DeleteDuplicates`) and slecting sub-lists with length of 9 (all distinct values). Finally one can delete empty lists by repeatedly applying rule `{} -> Nothing` and see if something is left in the end.

Comment: Using your code that is stated after 'One can also solve for particular x:' is there a way to filter those solutions for the ones where: $$n_1\ne n_2\ne n_3\ne n_4\ne n_5\ne n_6\ne n_7\ne n_8\ne n_9$$ This is the ultimate problem that I would like to solve.

Comment: They all have distinct values, but some are repeated (as 1, 29, 41 for x=3051). What do you mean?

Comment: I am looking for a unique solution such that all the values for n1,n2,...n9 are not equal to each other. In the solved case of x=3051 that is not true because of n1=n9 for example.

Comment: Is there a way to filter the solutions to search for the unique solution. I tried:

     x = 3051;
    Solve[{x == n1^2 + n2^2 + n3^2, x == n4^2 + n5^2 + n6^2, 
      x == n7^2 + n8^2 + n9^2, x == n1^2 + n4^2 + n7^2, 
      x == n2^2 + n5^2 + n8^2, x == n3^2 + n6^2 + n9^2, 
      x == n1^2 + n5^2 + n9^2, 
      n1 != n2 != n3 != n4 != n5 != n6 != n7 != n8 != n9}, {n1, n2, n3, 
      n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9}, PositiveIntegers]

But that gave a errormessage

Comment: It is possible that there is no solution, but I would like to know how to code that in Mathematica.

Comment: To check if all the solution are unique one can do like this: `Select[DeleteDuplicates /@ Values[sol], Length[#] == 9 &]`, where `sol` is the output of `Solve` for particular  `x` in my answer. Here we delete duplicates values from each solution and see if the length is 9, that means we deleted nothing and all the values are distinct. I tried this with `x=3051` and it gives `{}`, so there is no unique solution in this case.

Comment: Is it possible that you show me how you coded that using your code stated after: 'One can also solve for particular x:'?

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I tried: sol = ParallelTable[
   Solve[{x == n1^2 + n2^2 + n3^2, x == n4^2 + n5^2 + n6^2, 
     x == n7^2 + n8^2 + n9^2, x == n1^2 + n4^2 + n7^2, 
     x == n2^2 + n5^2 + n8^2, x == n3^2 + n6^2 + n9^2, 
     x == n1^2 + n5^2 + n9^2}, {n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9}, 
    PositiveIntegers], {x, 0, 10000}];
Select[DeleteDuplicates /@ Values[sol], Length[#] == 9 &] . But that does not work, can you show me why?

Comment: In case of `ParallelTable` the `sol` has more complicated structure and you need to map at 2nd level (at all sub-lists): `Map[Select[Length[#] == 9 &]@*DeleteDuplicates, Values[sol], {2}]`, here `@*` is composition of functions. I tried with `x` up to 1000, this gives many empty lists `{}`, one can use then `% //. {} -> Nothing` to remove all `{}` and see if somthing is left.

Comment: That looks indeed more complicated, can you add that to your answer? I do not get code that works using the paralleltable function.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your time and effort I really appreciate it. Last question I have, what does the {2} do in the Map function? Why is it {2} and not like {5}?

Comment: `{2}` in `Map` means 2nd level: by default `Map` works at 1st level (i.e. elements of plain list), but we have nested list and we need to map at sub-lists, and they are at 2nd level of `sol`. You can see this in help on `Map` function.

Comment: Okay, so the {2} does not change when I, for example, add more equations that the solutions have to satisfy?

Comment: Use `{2}` in case of `ParallelTable` or simple `Map` if you consider a particular `x`

Answer (score 2):

```
mm = Partition[Array[Subscript[n, #] &, 9], 3];
TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ mm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  n_1 & n_2 & n_3 \\
>  n_4 & n_5 & n_6 \\
>  n_7 & n_8 & n_9 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

We can restate the problem as *finding a 3X3 matrix of distinct square integers with identical row and column sums*.

#### *"to check if the system of equations gives a solution for a certain value of x?"*

For the related problem, *given an integer `x` find a 3X3 matrix of distinct square integers such that every row and every column sum to `x`*, we can use a semi-brute-force approach using `IntegerPartitions` of `x` with 3 elements restricting elements to square numbers.

```
xx = 314;
ip = IntegerPartitions[xx, {3}, Range[Ceiling[xx^(1/2)]]^2];
{{289, 16, 9}, {256, 49, 9}, {225, 64, 25}, {169, 144, 1}, {169, 81, 64}, {144, 121, 49}}
```

Construct 3X3 matrices taking 3-subsets of `ip` and select the duplicate-free ones:

```
dupFreeMatrices = Select[DuplicateFreeQ[Join @@ #] &]@Subsets[ip, {3}];
MatrixForm /@ dupFreeMatrices
```

[image]

The rows in each of these matrices sum to `314` by construction.

We next check if we can re-organize any of these matrices by permuting row elements to get a matrix with desired column sums.

For `xx = 314` find that this impossible:

```
Join @@ ((Select[Total[#] == {xx,xx,xx} &]@Tuples[Permutations /@ #]) & /@ dupFreeMatrices)
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

Combining the steps into a function:

```
ClearAll[findMat]
findMat = Module[{cums = ConstantArray[#,3], 
   mats = Select[DuplicateFreeQ[Join @@ #] &] @ 
     Subsets[Select[DuplicateFreeQ]@IntegerPartitions[#, {3}, 
        Range[Ceiling[#^(1/2)]]^2], {3}]},
  Join @@ ((Select[Total[#] == csums &]@Tuples[Permutations /@ #]) & /@ mats)]&;
```

Checking few entries from the list produced by OP's `ParallelTable`:

```
findMat /@ {314, 329, 341, 3051}
```

> ```
>  {{}, {}, {}, {}}
> ```

For `x` up to 10000, we find two numbers,`3249` and `3969`, for which we can find 9 distinct square integers satisfying the constraints in OP's system (1):

```
sols  = ParallelTable[findMat[n] /. {} -> Nothing, {n, 0, 10000}];


{Total[#[[1, 1]]], MatrixForm /@ #} & /@ sols
```

[image]

A faster version is to keep the first row and permute the second and third rows when we take `Tuples`:

```
ClearAll[findMat2]
findMat2 = Module[{csums = ConstantArray[#, 3], 
     mats = Select[DuplicateFreeQ[Join @@ #] &]@
       Subsets[Select[DuplicateFreeQ]@
         IntegerPartitions[#, {3}, Range[Ceiling[#^(1/2)]]^2], {3}]},
    Join @@ ((Select[Total[#] == csums &]@
          Tuples[{{#[[1]]}, Permutations[#[[2]]], 
            Permutations[#[[3]]]}]) & /@ mats)] &;

solsB = ParallelTable[findMat2[n] /. {} -> Nothing, {n, 0, 10000}];

{Total[#[[1, 1]]], MatrixForm /@ #} & /@ solsB
```

[image]

If we take all column permutations of matrices in `solsB` we get the longer lists in `sols`.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your answer. Now if I want to test this at a bigger scale is it possible to use the ParallelTable function, to check many more cases than one each time? Can you maybe show me your method using that?

Comment: @Jan, you can try the function `findMat` in `ParallelTable`.

Comment: I have no idea how to program using Mathematica. Can you help me combine the first and second code from my question, into the method that you're describing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jan, I meant you can try `ParallelTable[findMat[n] /. {} -> Nothing, {n, 0, 5000}]`

Comment: Yes I understand, thanks. How can I be sure that my equations are satisfied, because I do not see them being used in your code?

Comment: @Jan, (1) If you take the `Sqrt` of triples produced by `IntegerPartitions` 
 and sort them (`Sort[Sort /@ 
  Sqrt[IntegerPartitions[xx, {3}, Range[Ceiling[xx^(1/2)]]^2]]]`) you get the same list produced by `Select[FreeQ[0]]@PowersRepresentations[xx, 3, 2]` . The condition _each column should add up to `xx`_ (`Total[#] =={xx,xx,xx}`) is the same as the last 3 conditions in your system (1). ...

Comment: ...So we are first finding candidates that satisfy your first three conditions (each row adds up to xx) and then checking if we can satisfy your last three conditions by reshuffling each row (this does not change the row sums).

Comment: I find no solutions using the following code: ClearAll[findMat]
findMat = 
  Module[{cums = ConstantArray[#, 3], 
     mats = Select[DuplicateFreeQ[Join @@ #] &]@
       Subsets[Select[DuplicateFreeQ]@
         IntegerPartitions[#, {3}, Range[Ceiling[#^(1/2)]]^2], {3}]}, 
    Join @@ ((Select[Total[#] == csums &]@
          Tuples[Permutations /@ #]) & /@ mats)] &;
sols = ParallelTable[findMat[n] /. {} -> Nothing, {n, 0, 5000}];
{Total[#[[1, 1]]], MatrixForm /@ #} & /@ sols

Comment: Okay I get the solutions now. Now If I want to solve the following problem: Find a 7X7 matrix of distinct cubed integers with identical row and column sums. How can I program that?

Comment: Using that, I can see what I have to add to solve different problem likes the one you solved using your code.

Comment: @Jan, with larger systems `Tuples`+`Permutations` combination is not a good idea.

Comment: Okay thanks, what is the way to go when I want to find a 7X7 matrix of distinct cubed integers with identical row and column sums? Can you help me to program that

Comment: Do you have an idea how to find the 7X7 matrix?

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. Do you have the time to help me with the 7X7 matrix? Thank you in advance.